# Is there a Java equivalent to the C# partitioner

Tags: c#, java, multithreading, partitioning, fork-join

In my current project I am attempting to replicate the following functionality in Java, but I am unsure what this portion of code is doing exactly.

```
// This is C# code
if (numberOfMessages < 10)
{
     // just do it inline it's less expensive than spinning threads
     ReceiveTask(ct, numberOfMessages);
}
else
{
     // use the default partitioner to determine the number of tasks
     Parallel.ForEach(Partitioner.Create(0, numberOfMessages),
           (range) => ReceiveTask(ct, range.Item2 - range.Item1));
}
```

From my analysis of the comments I believe that when the number of messages is greater than 10 the code uses the Partitioner function of C# to create several threads where the number of messages being received is divided "equally" among the threads.

Furthermore, in later sections of this method the comments make references to the messages received from RecieveTask being stored in a Red Black Tree. Evaluation of the RecieveTask method does not reveal any implementation of such sorting which begs the question of whether the Partitioner does this as well.

Can someone please confirm or correct my understanding of the C# Partitioner function, and also give me some idea as to how to accomplish this task in Java? My experience with the Java concurrent library is limited and I did not see such an option available.

**EDIT 1:**

I have found the source of the sorting, RecieveTask adds messages to a SortedSet.

**EDIT 2:**

It appears that the partitioner is only dividing the tasks into groups, but it is the Parallel function that creates the multiple threads.

If I call Java's ForkJoinPool as suggested in the comments will this partitioning happen automatically, or will I need to divide the work myself?

If I must divide the amount of work, how would I call multiple instances of the FutureTask with the variable range of messages?

Comment: In Java 7, the closest I can think of is [ForkJoinPool](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html)

Comment: When you pass the two integers to the Partitioner.Create method, I believe the indexes just get split into multiple ranges. The partitioner never sees the source array so there is no way any sorting could be done.

Comment: I have found the source of the sorting after some more digging. I have edited the question to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is you divide the work yourself.

When coming to threading and parallel computing, there is no magic. All the nice and neat format comes with price - just if you realize it or it's hidden somewhere in the implementation code.

Dynamically forking threads doesn't seem to me a good idea, due to the uncertainty of number of threads you are creating, and threads themselves are objects which taking resources. If you are on some industrial project. I'd suggest to use a thread pool, which in Java is ExecutorService. Then you are free to call ExecutorService.invokeAll() if you don't care about the order of executions.

Red-black tree equivilent in Java is TreeSet/TreeMap, which can naturally give you a subset of it by calling headSet(), trailSet() and subSet() methods. Thus you might up to a small amout of coding here, but all seems to me pretty simple and neat, in both coding style and performance.